# apple login on nestjs + react-native ios app

Tags: ios, react-native, nestjs

I am implementing apple login using nestjs and react-native.

I am trying to decode the Apple token to sign up for my service and return my jwt.

My service uses email as a unique ID.

However, users can use private email for Apple login.

When the token is decoded, the email value is strange.

email: 'djw2fsapx@privaterelay.appleid.com'

Is this value fixed?

There are a lot of things in my service that require me to send an email.
Is this value still available unless the user unsubscribes?

Is there any way I can find out the none private email in the token?
If not, I wonder what is the value that must be fixed in the token.

```js
{
  iss: 'https://appleid.apple.com',
  aud: 'sssssssssssss',
  exp: 1654057611,
  iat: 1653971211,
  sub: '001301.0aeccb0efd674518855d5aab1ac0f.0739',
  nonce: '277e7887a2d367227d8079e62594e7d8544c22560359a63716b68702a4',
  c_hash: '0iBVxdsuqvkjOx_zLDA',
  email: 'djw2fsapx@privaterelay.appleid.com',
  email_verified: 'true',
  is_private_email: 'true',
  auth_time: 1653971211,
  nonce_supported: true
}
```

Is the sub value fixed to the ID?
Whether I choose private email or real email?

Some values ​​have been changed for security.

Wait for your reply. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, apple is just setting up a redirect from the encoded email to the "real" email but this encoded email is fixed. You can use that weird looking email as if it were any other because apple will take care of forwarding any email you send to the "real" email.

That email will remain open so long as their associated apple-id (the real email) is still valid.

The reason apple do this is to allow users to close a certain account by simply removing that email, which for you is the same risk for you as with any other email. There is no way for you to find out the original apple email (that is the point of the system).